# Filtering Objects in loop and set new State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that is something like this one in my react state:

```
timers:
  {
   id:"-LL-YVYNC_BGirSn1Ydu"
   title: "Project Title"
   project: "Project Name",
   elapsed: 0,
   runningSince: 0,
  },
  {
   id:"-LL-YVYNC_BGirSn1Ydu-2",
   title: "Project Title 2"
   project: "Project Name",
   elapsed: 0,
   runningSince: 0,
  },
  {
   id:"-LL-YVYNC_BGirSn1Ydu-3",
   title: "Project Title 3"
   project: "Project Name 2",
   elapsed: 0,
   runningSince: 0,
  }
```

Sometimes i need to bulk delete "timers" with the same "project" and update the state without them. I have an array like:

```
items=["-LL-YVYNC_BGirSn1Ydu", "-LL-YVYNC_BGirSn1Ydu-2"]
```

containing the id's of the items I need to remove.
I am using this method to achieve the result:

```
handleDeleteProject = (projectId)=>{
   //Creates the array with the id of removing elements
   let rObject = this.findTimers(projectId);
    for (const key of Object.keys(rObject)){
      tObject=[...this.state.timers];
      tObject = tObject.filter(timer=>timer.id !== rObject[key]);
      this.setState({
        timers: tObject
      })     
    }  
  }
```

The problem is that the items are filtered but for every loop "tObject" has the same values of the starting item so at the end of the loop i have an object filtered only by the last id in the array.
How can I remove all the items from the state, with or without "filter".
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
let rObject = this.findTimers(projectId);
let values = Object.values(rObject);
let tObject = this.state.timers.filter(timer => values.indexOf(timer.id) === -1);
this.setState({
  timers: tObject
});
```

that will solve it, with one filter only... `values` has all the values that needs to be avoided

edit: you could also do for the filter `(timer => !values.includes(timer.id))` instead of the `values.indexOf(...)...`

Comment: This is the correct solution but since values has simple strings just use values.includes(timer.id) it is easier to read.

Comment: includes is not compatible with IE... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: He did not mention needing compatibility with ie. Not everyone does, if so then of course use indexOf. Otherwise use the more readable solution.

Comment: @UXDart Also one more thing is that most people use babel-preset-env in the build.. so I think it is fine..

Comment: Both methods works great, thanks, I will stick with indexOf, for the moment.